# javascript window scroll issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on javascript scroll. I have following html code

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rVVuc/)**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="red div current"></div>
    <div class="blue div"></div>
    <div class="green div"></div>
    <div class="yellow div"></div>
</div>
```

In above code I have four div tags `red, blue, green and yellow`. All of them are position in following css.

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}
.div {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
.red {
    background: red;
}
.blue {
    background: blue;
}
.green {
    background: green;
}
.yellow {
    background: yellow;
}
```

In above html and css the red div tag is the current one which means user is seeing the red div tag on the screen. Now what I am trying to do is when user scroll over window once, then the next div tag i.e. blue will be animated and moved to the top and will become visible to the user whereas the red div tag will be behind the blue one. This same process goes for both green and yellow.

The problem is that when user scroll once then the div tag should animate however my current javascript code is keep reading the scroll and animating the div tags one after another. **What I want is when user scroll once then scroll should be disabled until the blue div tag is animated. Then scroll should be enabled. Again when user scroll second time, the scroll should disable until the green div tag completes its animation. Same goes for yellow.**

**How can I achieve above?**

Here is my javascript

```
$(window).on("scroll", function () {
    var next = $('.current').next();
    var height = next.outerHeight();

    next.animate({top: '-=' + height}, 500, function () {
        $(this).prev().removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look on update **[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rVVuc/5/)**

```
$(window).on("scroll", function () {
var next = $('.current').next();
var height = $('.current').outerHeight();
$('.current').prevAll().each(function(){
    height += $(this).outerHeight();
});

next.animate({top: '-=' + height}, 500, function () {
    $(this).prev().css('top','');
    $(this).prev().toggleClass('current');
    $(this).toggleClass('current');
});
```

});

Comment: it doesn't work they I want. It currently when I scroll once it changes div tag to blue tag then back to red.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason your example wasn't working as expected is because you were relatively positioning the divs, and not moving them to the correct spot.

Working JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/seanjohnson08/rVVuc/6/

```
.wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.div {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 100%;
}
.current{
    top: 0;
}
```

If you are looking for a way to limit the amount of scroll events fired, try throttling: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/. My solution doesn't require this, because no matter how many times it is firing the scroll event, it only ever tells jquery to animate to top:0, there's no chance of it animating past that.